# Making div scrollable when using ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I'm using ng-repeat to display some messages, and I'm trying to make the "message_area" scrollable as the messages naturally cause overflow over time, but my code doesn't work as expected.

```
<div class="main_area">

  <div id = "message_area" ng-repeat = "message in selected_conversation_object.messages.slice().reverse()">
    <div class="message_container" ng-if = "message.sender != me._id">
      <div class="message_received">{{message.message}}</div>
    </div>
    <div class="message_container" ng-if = "message.sender == me._id">
      <div class="message_sent_by_me">{{message.message}}</div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>

.main_area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 325px;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
}

#message_area {
  position: relative;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.message_container {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 30px;
}

.message_received {
}

.message_sent_by_me {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #0084FF;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  color: white;
  float: right;
}
```

I've not been able to understand why my code does not work.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a fiddle for your snippet.

Comment: Provide sample message data. That could help to test run the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `min-height` for the `#message_area` selector.

```
#message_area {
   position: relative;
   min-height: 50px; // Add This.
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use scroll to your `.main_area`. When the ever the data gets more than the given height it manages it with scroll bar on y-axis.

```
.main_area {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 325px;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background: white;
  **overflow-y: scroll;**
}
```

Working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UHUO2YkI11WzeXLpBki5?p=preview).